# Python module equivalent to the unix command "fmt"?

Tags: python, unix, python-module

There is some module with similar functionality to the unix command ["fmt"](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=fmt&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&arch=i386&format=html)?. `fmt` is pretty intelligent reflowing text and I would like to use something similar with some big strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
import textwrap

with open('long_text.txt', 'r') as f:
    long_text = f.read()

# Get a list of wrapped lines (default width 70)
long_text_lines = textwrap.wrap(long_text)

# Get a single string containing the wrapped text
# Same as: "\n".join(textwrap.wrap(long_text, ...))
long_text_string = textwrap.fill(long_text)
```